# roots child theme can't override header.php

Tags: templates, child-theme, theme-roots

I made a child theme for roots and it worked as expected. I can override everything, including footer.php, but not header.php. My header.php looks exactly like the one from roots at the moment, except for the blog title, which I replaced. I googled it, but it seems that I'm the only one facing this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to clarify, are you referring to [this theme](http://www.rootstheme.com/)? If so, it doesn't appear to use the architecture of a typical theme - you'll need to copy `roots/templates/head.php` to `child/templates/head.php` and modify accordingly.

Comment: Yes that is the theme Im talking about. But why head.php? I need to change header.php, because I want to modify the call for wp_nav_menu and I dont know how to do it via hook. And yes, I used the templates folder. In forum posts I saw that other people did the same thing with root's header.php and succeeded.

Comment: So you copied `roots/templates/header.php` to `child/templates/header.php` & modified?

Comment: Have you also tried the same with `header-top-navbar.php`?

Comment: Roots is now using theme wrappers as described in [this post](http://scribu.net/wordpress/theme-wrappers.html) by @scribu

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I did. And no, I haven't tried yet. I later will. I just googled it. Why does it contain another wp_nav_menu?

Comment: If you check out `base.php` you'll see why